# bind parameter from a collection

Tags: angularjs

Below I have function called `setProject()` inside this function I have to send `Id` but value is not binding.

```
<tr ng-repeat="Project in Projects">
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" ng-click="setProject({{Project.Id}})"/> {{Project.Nm}}
            </div>
        </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `ng-click` you don't need to interpolate `{ }`:

Change this:

```
ng-click="setProject({{Project.Id}})"
```

To this:

```
ng-click="setProject(Project.Id)"
```

The `ng-click` directive is already away of the Angular context in this case.  It takes an [Angular Expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) as input.

Comment: ya, i got that thanks.